# Conducting Chaos Engineering

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have 28 micro-services, some of which communicates with each other.  All of them are built with SpringBoot 2x and they use their own resources (database, rabbitmq etc.).  They are deployed in PCF.

I need to identify weakness of the overall system. That's when I resorted to Chaos Engineering. As this is my first time, I can use some help regarding how to design the effort, what metrics should I collect, tools that I can use, how long should I run such tests etc.

TIA

Comment: Have a look at this tool - https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy/wiki/Chaos-Monkey

Answer (score 0):

Done with my research.  Posting it here so that someone else might find it useful.

Very good introductions including how to start your first chaos experiment: https://www.gremlin.com/community/tutorials/chaos-engineering-the-history-principles-and-practice/

Good summary of people, tools, companies doing chaos experiments:
https://coggle.it/diagram/WiKceGDAwgABrmyv/t/chaos-engineeringcompanies%2C-people%2C-tools-practices/0a2d4968c94723e48e1256e67df51d0f4217027143924b23517832f53c536e62

**Tools:**

Spinnaker: https://www.spinnaker.io/.  Netflix Chaos Monkey does not support deployments that are managed by anything other than Spinnaker. That makes it pretty hard to use Chaos Monkey from Netflix.

ChaosMonkey for SpringBoot: https://docs.chaostoolkit.org/drivers/cloudfoundry/.  Very easy to follow instructions.  Easy to turn on/off using Spring profile.

Chaos Toolkit - https://docs.chaostoolkit.org/drivers/cloudfoundry/.  This tool is particularly helpful to my situation since my applications are deployed in Cloud Foundry and this tool has a CloudFoundry extension.  Pretty elaborate, but easy to follow instructions.  My preferred tool so far.

Chaos Lemur - https://content.pivotal.io/blog/chaos-lemur-testing-high-availability-on-pivotal-cloud-foundry.  This tool has promise but network admin won't share AWS credentials for me to muck with Pivotal cells.

Answer (score 0):

You already found Chaos Toolkit, which is what I would recommend for the actual experimenting, especially when starting out.

The basis of Chaos is that you need to plan it out and analyse properly before starting out. And then you need to find out what kind of information you will need to monitor the results of the experiment. What happens to service X if we implement latency? Monitor requests, errors etc. Is there a functioning degraded state or is it just dead?

Your question is very broad and as such it's difficult to answer.

Make sure to try to prevent cascading failures whenever you start an experiment and always have stop that terminates the experiment and rolls everything back should something break really bad.